# VBA- Automating pivot tables- Range issues

Tags: vba, excel, pivot, pivot-table

I'm trying to generate a pivot table from a table (listobject) named ProjectList on Sheet3 of my workbook.

What I've got is as follows, but I get an error message (1004) when I try to run it.

```
Dim PivotTableCache As PivotCache
Dim PT As PivotTable

Worksheets("Pivot Table Category").Delete
Sheets.Add
ActiveSheet.Name = "Pivot Table Category"

Set PivotTableCache = ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, _
        SourceData:=Range("ProjectList"))

Sheets("Pivot Table Category").Select

Set PT = PivotTableCache.CreatePivotTable(TableDestination:=Range(1, 1), _
        TableName:="PivotCategory")
```

`

I've also tried a variation where I drop in the following at the beginning

```
Dim PRange As Range
Set PRange = Sheet3.ListObjects("ProjectList").DataBodyRange
```

and refer to PRange when setting up the PivotCache, but that doesn't work either.

Any ideas where I'm going wrong?  I have a vague notion that it may be related to the sourcetype.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One fell swoop can do it:

```
  Dim PT as PivotTable
  Set PT = ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:= _
        "ProjectList", Version:=xlPivotTableVersion14).CreatePivotTable (TableDestination _
        :="Pivot Table Category!R1C1", TableName:="PivotCategory", DefaultVersion:= _
        xlPivotTableVersion14)
```

Comment: Okay, I figured out the issue here, the above works, but is missing an open parenthesis.  Should read as follows:


`Set PT = ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:= "ProjectList", Version:=xlPivotTableVersion14).CreatePivotTable(TableDestination:="PivotSheet1!R1C1", TableName:="PivotCategory", DefaultVersion:=xlPivotTableVersion14)`

Comment: Thanks @MaggieZ. Yes, I forgot to enclose parens when I added `Set`. I edited code. Glad you got it worked out. If you feel this one or the other answer solved your issue, please mark as answered so others can benefit who come here later.

Answer (score 0):

Your range reference for the destination is incorrect. It should be

```
Set PT = PivotTableCache.CreatePivotTable(TableDestination:=Cells(1, 1), TableName:="PivotCategory")
'OR
Set PT = PivotTableCache.CreatePivotTable(TableDestination:=Range("A1"), TableName:="PivotCategory")
```

Comment: Definitely accurate, but not a fix. Now I'm getting "The PivotTable field name is not valid.....If you are changing the name of a PivotTable field, you must type a new name for the field"

Comment: What is the field name?

Comment: Field Name is "Category"

Comment: Yes, and it doesn't compile-  I get "Expected: End of Statement"  and when I play with it, it want the statement to end before creating the pivot table and after creating the pivot cache, so what I was doing to begin with.

Comment: Do you have any blank cells in your header row?

Comment: No, I don't.  I have a "Column N" etc, but nothing blank.

Comment: Check you don't have illegal characters in any headers, and that there are no hidden columns or merged cells.

Comment: I got Scott's solution working, I think.  Thank you so much for your help!!